# How to update an array using mongo and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongo document such as:

```
{
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#7 (1) {
  ["$id"]=>
  string(24) "506f54886801cae34212c1a2"
  }
  ["hhid"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(210854544)
   [1]=>
   int(308789420)
 }
 ["seg"]=>
 array(4) {
   [0]=>
   int(71)
    [1]=>
    int(91)
    [2]=>
    int(35)
    [3]=>
    int(64)
  }
}
```

what I'd like to do is to update the `seg` array (add another entry) where `hhid` has a particular element.

I have tried:

```
$collection->update(
    array('hhid' => '226304795'),
    array('$addToSet' => array("seg" => "8")));
```

Expecting the seg array to now have:

> ```
> ["seg"]=>
>   array(5) {
>     [0]=>
>     int(71)
>     [1]=>
>     int(91)
>     [2]=>
>     int(35)
>     [3]=>
>     int(64)
>     [4]=>
>     int(8)
>  }
> ```

However nothing happens. I understand `hhid` is an array, but I don't think the criteria is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are enclosing a variable in single quotes; this way PHP will interpret it literally. Try removing the single quotes from `'$addToSet'`.

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you want the value from $addToSet as your key, you don't need quotes at all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Removing the single quotes did not help.  I believe the issue is with the assertion, since its an array search array('hhid' => '226304795'). If I did not have an array for  the assertion, then the update works fine.

Comment: The `$addToSet` is a MongoDB query command as such should be interpreted by PHP as literal. If you remove the quotes it will not function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are searching by `string` when infact you want to search by `int` as your document shows:

```
["hhid"]=>
  array(2) {
      [0]=>int(210854544)
      [1]=>int(308789420)
  }
```

MongoDB has no knowledge of your types (unless using a BSON type but even then won't convert unlike SQL) and it is not loosely typed like PHP so searching string on a int field will not work. Try instead:

```
$collection->update(
    array('hhid' => 226304795),
    array('$addToSet' => array("seg" => "8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

??? `226304795` is not in your `hhid` array, right?

So you can't find anything to update.

Here is my testing data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5088c3396c27125921108707"), "hhid" : [ 210854544, 308789420 ], "seg" : [ 71, 91, 35, 64 ] }
```

My code:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = $m->test;
$test = $db->test;
$test->update(array('hhid'=>210854544), array('$addToSet' => array('seg' => 8)));
```

And my result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5088c6fa6c27125921108708"), "hhid" : [ 210854544, 308789420 ], "seg" : [ 71, 91, 35, 64, 8 ] }
```

It works :)

Also, notice the value type(`hhid` and values in `seg`). Don't surround values with double quotes if you want to store or find `int` values.